# error in redirect to other page using php

Tags: php, html

In my project im getting such kind of error when im trying to redirect to another page when the person submit the contact form then it should redirect to some other page but im getting such kind of error. the error what im getting is this

> warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\grade\header.php:89) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\grade\contact.php on line 64

**header.php**

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <title>SAMSON SOLAR ENERGY</title>

            <!-- Meta tag Keywords -->
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="keywords" content="Grade Responsive web template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Android Compatible web template, 
            Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyEricsson, Motorola web design" />
            <script type="application/x-javascript">
                addEventListener("load", function () {
                    setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0);
                }, false);

                function hideURLbar() {
                    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
                }
            </script>
            <!--// Meta tag Keywords -->

            <!-- css files -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"> <!-- Bootstrap-Core-CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> <!-- Style-CSS --> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome-all.css"> <!-- Font-Awesome-Icons-CSS -->
            <!-- //css files -->
                <!----->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="all" /><!-- for testimonials -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <!--web font-->
            <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,900,900i&amp;subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,greek,greek-ext,latin-ext,vietnamese" rel="stylesheet">
            <!--//web font-->

        </head>

        <body>

        <!-- header -->
        <header>
            <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                <span class="fa fa-strikethrough"></span> SAMSON SOLAR
                    </a>

                    <button class="navbar-toggler ml-md-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto text-center">
                            <li class="nav-item active  mr-lg-3">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item  mr-lg-3">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="about.php">about</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item  mr-lg-3">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="gallery.php">Gallery</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown mr-lg-3">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="domestic.php">Domestic</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="commercial.php">Commercial</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="other.php">Other Products</a>
                    </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">contact</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="buttons">
                            <p><i class="fas mr-1 fa-phone"></i> +91 99161 67190</p>
                </div>
                    </div>
            </nav>
            </div>

            <div class="icon-bar">
                <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a> 
                <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a> 
                <a href="#" class="google"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></a> 
                <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a> 
            </div>

        </header>
        <!-- //header -->
```

**contact.php**

```
        <?php include 'header.php'; ?>

        <!-- banner -->
        <section class="inner-banner">
            <div class="banner-layer">
                <h1 class="text-center">Contact Page</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- //banner -->

        <?php 
            include_once 'connect.php';
            $nameErr = $emailErr = $contactErr = "";
            $name = $email = $contact = $subject = "";

            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
            {
                //Name 
                if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
                    $nameErr = "Please enter your Name";
                } 
                    else{
                        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
                        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                            $nameErr = "Sorry Only letters are allowed"; 
                        }
                    }

                    //E-mail ID
                    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
                        $emailErr = "Please enter your E-mail ID";
                        } 
                    else{
                        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
                        // check if the entered Email-id is valid or not
                            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                                $emailErr = "Please enter a valid E-mail ID"; 
                            }
                        }

                    //Contact Number
                    if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
                        $contactErr = "Please enter your Contact Number";
                    } 
                    else{
                        $contact = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
                        // check weather the contact number is valid or not
                        if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/",$contact)) {
                            $contactErr = "Please enter Your 10 Digit mobile Number"; 
                        }
                    }

                    //Reason For contacting
                    if (!empty($_POST["subject"])) {
                        $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
                    } 

                    if($nameErr == "" && $emailErr == "" && $contactErr == ""){
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO contact(`ID`,`Name`, `Email`, `Contact_no` , `Reason`)
                                VALUES ('','".$name."', '".$email."', '".$contact."' , '".$subject."')";

                if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
                            header("location:contact_success.php");
                            exit();
                        }
                else{
                                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
                            } 
                            mysqli_close($mysqli);
                    }

            }

            function test_input($data) {
                    $data = trim($data);
                    $data = stripslashes($data);
                    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                    return $data;
                }

        ?>

    <!-- contact -->
    <section class="contact py-5">
        <div class="container">
        <h2 class="heading mb-lg-5 mb-4">Contact Us</h2>
        <div class="row contact-grids w3-agile-grid">
                <div class="row col-md-6 col-sm-6 contact-grid1 w3-agile-grid">
            <div class="col-3 text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-9 p-0">
                        <h4>Get In Touch</h4><br>
                        <p><b>Mobile:</b> <a href="tel:+91 9916167190">+91 9916167190</a></p>
                        <p><b>E-mail:</b> <a href="mailto:abpaple@gmail.com">abpaple@gmail.com</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row col-md-6 col-sm-6 mt-sm-0 mt-4 contact-grid1 w3-agile-grid">
            <div class="col-3 text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9 p-0">
                        <h4>Visit Our Location</h4><br>
                        <p><b>SAMSON SOLAR ENERGY</b></p>
                        <p>#02, K.E.Board Complex, Navalgund Road, Shivaji Circle</p>
                        <p>DHARWAD-580008, KARNATAKA, INDIA</p>
            </div>
                </div>
        </div><br><br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="gmap_canvas">
                        <iframe width="100%" height="475" id="gmap_canvas" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=SAMSON%20SOLAR%20ENERGY%20%20%2302%2C%20K.E.Board%20Complex%2C%20Navalgund%20Road%2C%20Shivaji%20Circle%20%20DHARWAD-580008%2C%20KARNATAKA%2C%20INDIA&t=&z=13&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <h2 style="margin-bottom:15px">Write To Us</h2>
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" value="<?php if (isset($name)) echo $name; ?>">
                            <span style="color:red;"> <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter E-mail" name="email" value="<?php if (isset($email)) echo $email; ?>">
                            <span style="color:red;"> <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Contact Number" name="phone" value="<?php if (isset($contact)) echo $contact; ?>">
                            <span style="color:red;"> <?php echo $contactErr;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter Reason For Contacting" name="subject"><?php if (isset($subject)) echo $subject; ?></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="submit">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- //contact -->

    <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

please can any one help me to solve my issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: hey @Nick i read that answer but it did not solved my problem. please can u halp me a bit more

Comment: As soon as you output **anything** (as `header.php` does), headers are sent. You cannot then send another header as you are trying to do in `contact.php`. The linked answer explains this quite clearly.

Comment: You echo something before the header, move your html code after php code

Comment: use ob_clean() Method before redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of reason for the error: `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent` below are some of them:

1. `print` and `echo` statements will terminate the opportunity to send HTTP headers
2. `<html>` before any `header()` call.
3. Whitespace before `<?php`
4. Whitespace after ?>
5. Preceding error messages can also be a cause of this error.

If You want to check all reasons in detail then here is [referenced stackoveflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php/8028987#8028987)

But for you the reason of this error is that, you have included Raw  sections prior 
 to `<?php` code, you can not include html before php code.

In your code you are including `header.php` and `<section>` which is html, before `php` code therefor you are getting this error, so for solving it change your

**contact.php** file as below

```
<?php 
        include_once 'connect.php';
        $nameErr = $emailErr = $contactErr = "";
        $name = $email = $contact = $subject = "";

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
        {
            //Name 
            if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
                $nameErr = "Please enter your Name";
            } 
                else{
                    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
                    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                        $nameErr = "Sorry Only letters are allowed"; 
                    }
                }

                //E-mail ID
                if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
                    $emailErr = "Please enter your E-mail ID";
                    } 
                else{
                    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
                    // check if the entered Email-id is valid or not
                        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                            $emailErr = "Please enter a valid E-mail ID"; 
                        }
                    }

                //Contact Number
                if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
                    $contactErr = "Please enter your Contact Number";
                } 
                else{
                    $contact = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
                    // check weather the contact number is valid or not
                    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/",$contact)) {
                        $contactErr = "Please enter Your 10 Digit mobile Number"; 
                    }
                }

                //Reason For contacting
                if (!empty($_POST["subject"])) {
                    $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
                } 

                if($nameErr == "" && $emailErr == "" && $contactErr == ""){
                $sql = "INSERT INTO contact(`ID`,`Name`, `Email`, `Contact_no` , `Reason`)
                            VALUES ('','".$name."', '".$email."', '".$contact."' , '".$subject."')";

            if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
                        header("location:contact_success.php");
                        exit();
                    }
            else{
                            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
                        } 
                        mysqli_close($mysqli);
                }

        }

        function test_input($data) {
                $data = trim($data);
                $data = stripslashes($data);
                $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                return $data;
            }

    ?>
    <?php include 'header.php'; ?>

    <!-- banner -->
    <section class="inner-banner">
        <div class="banner-layer">
            <h1 class="text-center">Contact Page</h1>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- //banner -->

 <!-- contact -->
<section class="contact py-5">
    <div class="container">
    <h2 class="heading mb-lg-5 mb-4">Contact Us</h2>
    <div class="row contact-grids w3-agile-grid">
            <div class="row col-md-6 col-sm-6 contact-grid1 w3-agile-grid">
        <div class="col-3 text-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
                <div class="col-9 p-0">
                    <h4>Get In Touch</h4><br>
                    <p><b>Mobile:</b> <a href="tel:+91 9916167190">+91 9916167190</a></p>
                    <p><b>E-mail:</b> <a href="mailto:abpaple@gmail.com">abpaple@gmail.com</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row col-md-6 col-sm-6 mt-sm-0 mt-4 contact-grid1 w3-agile-grid">
        <div class="col-3 text-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-9 p-0">
                    <h4>Visit Our Location</h4><br>
                    <p><b>SAMSON SOLAR ENERGY</b></p>
                    <p>#02, K.E.Board Complex, Navalgund Road, Shivaji Circle</p>
                    <p>DHARWAD-580008, KARNATAKA, INDIA</p>
        </div>
            </div>
    </div><br><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="gmap_canvas">
                    <iframe width="100%" height="475" id="gmap_canvas" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=SAMSON%20SOLAR%20ENERGY%20%20%2302%2C%20K.E.Board%20Complex%2C%20Navalgund%20Road%2C%20Shivaji%20Circle%20%20DHARWAD-580008%2C%20KARNATAKA%2C%20INDIA&t=&z=13&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <h2 style="margin-bottom:15px">Write To Us</h2>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" value="<?php if (isset($name)) echo $name; ?>">
                        <span style="color:red;"> <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter E-mail" name="email" value="<?php if (isset($email)) echo $email; ?>">
                        <span style="color:red;"> <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Contact Number" name="phone" value="<?php if (isset($contact)) echo $contact; ?>">
                        <span style="color:red;"> <?php echo $contactErr;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter Reason For Contacting" name="subject"><?php if (isset($subject)) echo $subject; ?></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- //contact -->

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

And if problem remains the same after changing file as above then try to separate html file `contact.php` and make new php process file like `contact_process.php` and add php processing code only in `contact_process.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
    header("location:contact_success.php");
    exit();
}
```

You could do this:

```
if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
    echo "<script>window.location.href = 'contact_success.php';</script>";
    exit();
}
```

May not be conventional but it should work.